# Rails - def search issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

OK, I'm very new to Rails, so please be patient :)

I'm not sure how to structure the def search in the page controller so that it returns back the correct results (right now the results are blank). 
I'm adapting a course code to my project. The original course is showing how to search for room by address rather than through the drop down attribute selection. It was also ordering the results by distance rather than a price. Here is what I come up with for my project:

```
def search
    # STEP 1
    if params[:search].present? && params[:search].strip != ""
      session[:loc_search] = params[:search]
    end

    # STEP 2
    if session[:loc_search] && session[:loc_search] != ""
      @rooms_type = Room.where(active: true).order(session[:loc_search], order: 'price')
    else
      @rooms_type = Room.where(active: true).all
    end

    # STEP 3
    @search = @rooms_type.ransack(params[:q])
    @rooms = @search.result

    @arrRooms = @rooms.to_a

    end
```

I'm pretty sure that there are several mistakes in the def search.. could someone help me to figure this out?

Here are my Room model attribute.

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.string :type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Search widget on the homepage is structured in the following way:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <%= select_tag :type, options_for_select([['Single', 1], ['Double', 2]]), ,class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
    </div>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

The search page does the following:

```
<div class = "row">
  <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
    <div class = "col-md-4">
      <div class = "panel panel-default">
        <div class = "panel-heading preview">
          <% image_tag room.cover_photo (:medium)  %>
        </div>
        <div class = "panel-body">
          <% link_to room.type, room %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Thank you.

UPDATED code based on @crispychicken  feedback - see the screenshots enter image description here

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? - I think you need to add `=` to your image_tag and link_to helpers.

Comment: have you problems with the search form or the page results?

Comment: With the page results.. it is always blank, no results showing...

Answer (score 0):

First Issue: The content of your model is wrong. It belongs into a migration. Also, the `active` and `price` attributes are missing. And I think the attribute `type` is protected. You should rename it to something like RoomType.

To create the migration:

```
rails g migration create_rooms room_type:string active:boolean price:integer
```

And then do `rails db:migrate`

Second Issue:

In your controller, change the code in your Step 2 to:

```
@rooms_type = Room.where(active: true, room_type: session[:loc_search]).order(:price)
```

And you have to change `type` to `room_type` everywhere in your files.

Comment: made the changes you suggested, but the search page is still blank.. I attached the screenshot of the changes to the original question (I only used bedroom rather than room_type). What do I miss?? Is it possible that it has something to do with [:loc_search] in the page  controller? I've reused it from a course and not sure if it is relevant to the select_tag search option. Thanks